# Highlight specific text in specific order

Tags: jquery

I've got this but need it to highlight in order without hovering, so more like an animation. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/3QG3w/

In more detail: When the page loads I want "Client 1" to highlight and with it "Benefit 1" and "Benefit 3". Then I want it to un-highlight and "Client 2" and Benefit 2, 3 & 4 to highlight" and so on.. So it cycles through each Client highlighting the benefit for each. An animation of sorts.

Sorry, I'm fairly new to coding but trying my best.

Comment: what are you looking for. Can you elaborate your question.

Comment: sounds like a job for `setInterval()`

Comment: Please write your sentence in way that someone can understand

Comment: To actually animate the color change (fade in/out) you'd probably want to use the [Color Animations](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin. Otherwise you can use `setTimeout` to cycle through the three groups.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to emulate the highlighting as in a timed interval, you could use jquery with a variable to select the classes.
For example: http://jsfiddle.net/3QG3w/2/

(Code used: )

```
var i = 0;

function nextben(){
    if(i>0) $(".ben" + i).removeClass('highlight');
    if(++i>5)i=1;
    $(".ben" + i).addClass('highlight');
}

setInterval(nextben,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to do this. But you can animate is as shown in the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3QG3w/3/ (an update to your original fiddle)